Why is docker volume not responding to code changes?
I have a react app for which I have created a docker file named Dockerfile.dev
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR "/app"

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","start"]

To correspond to changes made in the code, I also have setup docker volume in my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3.2'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app


the dockerfile and the docker-compose file are on the same directory. But, when I change some code in the react app, I don't see the change applied to the localhost:port where the app is running.
I also checked the file system inside the container using docker exec, and the file system inside the container has reacted to the change. But, the actual application isn't reacting to the change. Is there something I am missing here?

Is something in your Node setup restarting or reloading the application when the code changes?  Is there anything Docker-specific here, or do you have the same problem just running npm run start without involving Docker at all?

I think it's docker specific. When I run npm run start without involving Docker and change something in the react app, the react app automatically restarts and the change is instantly reflected on the app.
